How to specify the repository for az repos pr policy list command?
The Microsoft documentation says that you can use az repos pr policy list --id to list the policies on a PR.
However, it gives no way to specify which repository the PR belongs to. How do I do this? I find it absurd that there is no --repository flag on this command, and I haven't been able to find a solution on google.

After further research, I can confirm that PR IDs are in fact unique across repositories, so specifying the repository is not needed.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You may use the commands below instead to know which repository the PR belongs to.
az repos pr show --id {prId}
az repos pr show --id {prId} --query "repository.name" --output tsv

As a PR is organizational unique, we don't need to specify the repository as an argument/parameter.
